# iOS 11 beta 9 empty keyboard keys

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9beta6

I've got this annoying bug while compiling my app with Xcode 9 beta 6.
it occurs on the simulator and on device.
the numeric keypad is working.
[image: default keyboard]

[image: numeric]

any idea ?

Comment: It's a bug (and very likely not an error in your code, unless you are working with private APIs), file a radar.

Comment: also occurs with ios 11 GM

Comment: Not compile. Run. File at https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

This happens in GM seed as well.

This is caused by an internal iOS 11 issue when the following extension is implemented. Remove the extension and the keyboard is back.

UIView+TintColor.h

```
#ifndef UIView_TintColor_h
#define UIView_TintColor_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIView (TintColor)
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIColor* tintColor;
@end
#endif /* UIView_TintColor_h */
```

UIView+TintColor.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "UIView+TintColor.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char const * const tintColorKey = "tintColorKey";

@implementation UIView (TintColor)

-(UIColor*)tintColor
{
    return  objc_getAssociatedObject(self , tintColorKey);
}

-(void)setTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, tintColorKey, tintColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```